# How to insert function() into $form->js()->submit()?

Tags: atk4

I want to execute function on Form submit, but I when i use `$form->js('submit`,array('function())` it works only when I click submit button, but doesn't work on Enter.

Is there a way to insert code in jquery function from php side of at4 like `$this-js()->submit('function(){alert('sth')})`

Comment: have you tried $form->js('submit')->univ()->alert('form submitted'); ?

Answer (score 1):

For those who will have the same problem. In atk4 when you press eneter in one of forms fields it calls atk4 function `submitForm()` without calling `form.submit()`. That is why binding something to `form.submit()` doesn't work with enter press. It can be solved by adding

```
$form->js(true)->find('input')->keypress("function(e) {
    if ($(this).is('.ui-autocomplete-input')) return true;
    if (e.keyCode==13) {
        $(this).trigger('change');
        ".$this->owner->js()->submit()."
        ev.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

and when you want to bind something with form submit, add:

```
 $form->js(true)->submit($form->js(false,"function(ev){}));`
```